# SQL Simple Query From Multiple Tables

Tags: sql

I would appreciate if anyone can give me a hand with this question

I have 4 SQL tables. Open, High, Low and Close.

Each have 2 columns called [Date],[Price].

The dates are the same - but Price is a number and is different.

How can we make a query where the results are as follows

```
[Date],[Open.Price],[High.Price],[Low.Price],[Close.Price]
```

Comment: Inner join with date colums

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Open_table.date,Open_table.Price,High_table.Price,low_table.Price,
       Close_table.Price
FROM Open_table
JOIN High_table ON Open_table.date = High_table.date
JOIN low_table ON Open_table.date = low_table.date
JOIN Close_table  ON Open_table.date = Close_table.date
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try joining on date:

```
SELECT t1.[Date],
       t1.[Price] AS [Open.Price],
       t2.[Price] AS [High.Price],
       t3.[Price] AS [Low.Price],
       t4.[Price] AS [Close.Price]
FROM Open t1
INNER JOIN High t2
    ON t1.[Date] = t2.[Date]
INNER JOIN Low t3
    ON t2.[Date] = t3.[Date]
INNER JOIN Close t4
    ON t3.[Date] = t4.[Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way of doing so after I posted this question

```
SELECT 
EuropeOpen.[Date],EuropeOpen.[OCDO LN],EuropeHigh.[Date],EuropeHigh.[OCDO LN],EuropeLow.[Date],EuropeLow.[OCDO LN],
EuropeClose.[Date],EuropeClose.[OCDO LN]

FROM EuropeOpen,EuropeHigh,EuropeLow,EuropeClose
```

// In case you need any conditions
WHERE....

Comment: That creates a cross product between all four tables. This is definitely **not** what you want. You **have** to join those table - ideally using an explicit `JOIN` as shown in the other answers.